# Way to encapsulate instance fields in Python

Tags: python, properties, decorator, encapsulation

Is this use of [@property decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) appropriate to obtain a good encapsulation of instance fields? I'm trying to achieve that Foobar class' clients can't assign arbitrary values to the field `vel` of Foobar instances in any way, de facto bypassing assignment rules defined in the property setter method.

Thanks.

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._vel = 0

    @property
    def vel(self):
        return self._vel

    @vel.setter
    def vel(self, v):
        self._vel = v if v > 0 else 0
```

The field seems well encapsulated.

```
>>> foobar = Foobar()
>>> foobar.vel
0
>>> foobar.vel = -1
>>> foobar.vel
0
>>> foobar.vel = 1
>>> foobar.vel
1
```

Comment: Note that it may be better practice to raise ValueError instead of silently clamping the value, which may be confusing.  I'd definitely do that if checking discrete values (eg. an enumerated type or string format checks); for a velocity I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent the user from bypassing anything in python. There's always a way to monkeypatch/reflect/inspect attributes; There's no object sandboxing support.

In your example:

```
>>> foobar._vel = -1
```

Would bypass the property entirely and assign directly to the real attribute. You can't prevent it at all. There are methods to make it harder, but the user can assign if she really wants to, so what's the point?

The usual approach seems to be to rely on the fact that the users of your library are adults and trust them:

Declare the range of expected values in the documentation and ask users to follow. If they don't it's their fault.

Comment: You're badly misunderstanding the principle of "we're all adults".  It doesn't mean "we're all perfect".  You can't prevent people from bypassing your API and assigning to `foobar._vel`, but it's perfectly normal to use accessors on your *public* methods (`foobar.vel`) to perform value checking.  Don't just mention things in documentation and try to pass the blame because your code doesn't do any value checking.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I don't know where you got that impression, but it seems that you're going against the majority of existing python libraries - it's hard to see that type of value checking in attribute level in a real well-known python library. It takes a lot of time (assignment in a property uses function call and is orders of magnitude slower than attribute assignment) for no gain in the general case. And the code will fail anyway if a wrong value is given so that check is really not that useful

Comment: People seem to use "we're all adults" as an excuse for anything.  It's perfectly reasonable to have sanity checks for values, just as you can't construct a date(month=13).  You're assuming that the "code will fail" in some nice, clean way, when in practice it may produce an invalid result much later or cause subtle, hard-to-trace bugs.  (This isn't a question about optimization.)